# Is every table of numbers a matrix?

Tags: matrices

In my understanding, a matrix is all of those:

- a transformation in a vector space,
- a function form some domain to some range,
- a shorthand way of describing a system of linear equations.

By the last point, a real-valued matrix can have any conceivable real numbers as elements. Is that true or does there exist a table of numbers, which cannot be interpreted as a matrix in the linear algebra sense?

Comment: Any two-dimensional, rectangular table of real numbers can be interpreted as a matrix, in the same way as any finite string of digits can be interpreted as a natural number.

Comment: Any $m \times n$ array of real numbers is a valid matrix representing a linear map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$. If you label the columns $a_1, a_2, \ldots a_n$, and let $e_1,e_2,\ldots e_n$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^n$, then the matrix $A = [a_1 a_2 \ldots a_n]$ maps $e_j$ to $a_j$ for each $j=1,2,\ldots n$. Similar statement holds for complex numbers; just change $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C$ above.

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \end{pmatrix}$ isn't a matrix.

Comment: In the most abstract of senses, you could define a matrix of values from a scalar field as a two-dimensional grid of entries such that each position in the grid contains a value from our scalar field.  A matrix is not inherently itself a transformation in a vector space, but it can certainly represent one and in finite dimensional vector spaces transformations can be represented by such a matrix.  Now... "is a table of numbers" you will need to be more clear as to what you mean by a table.  A [Young Tableau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau) might fit your definition of table.

Comment: That being said, if you wanted to get technical and particularly abstract, you could have a matrix whose entries are themselves matrices... so long as they come from a matrix field.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, a matrix is simply a rectangular array of numbers. It is *not* a linear map, although a linear map $f$ between two finite-dimensional vector space can be reconstructed from the matrix of $f$ with respect to two bases. It is also *not* a function. And, again, it is *not* a system of linear equations, although such a system can be condensed through a matrix.

And, in particular, yes, any *rectangular* table of numbers *is* a matrix.

Comment: One could argue that a matrix is a function, e.g. $\{1, \ldots, n\} \times \{1, \ldots, m\} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @mechanodroid Likely not what the OP had in mind, though.